# Problema con sentencia preparada al obtener varios registros y guardarlos en un array - PHP

Tags: php

El problema que tengo es que no se si estoy implementando mal el `fetch_assoc` o guardando mal los registros en el `**array** ya que al verificar si la consulta del **$stmt->execute()** falla, me dice que esta correcta y no me retorna nada.

La consulta me debe devolver más de 2 registros para luego manejarlos en otro archivo en donde los enviare a android mediante un `echo` con `json_encode`.

```
public function searchMiembrosGrupo($id_grupo){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `email_padre`,`nombre_hijo` FROM `hijos` INNER JOIN `user` WHERE `hijos`.`email_padre` = `user`.`email` AND `user`.`grupo` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()) {
          $miembros_grupo[] = $row;

    }
    return $miembros_grupo;

}
```

**SearchMiembro.php**

```
<?php 

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['id_grupo'])) {

// receiving the post params
$id_grupo = $_POST['id_grupo'];

// get the user by email and password
var_dump($user = $db->searchMiembrosGrupo($id_grupo));
//$user = $db->searchMiembrosGrupo($id_grupo);

if ($user != false) {
    // user is found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["user"]["email_padre"] = $user["email_padre"];
    $response["user"]["nombre_hijo"] = $user["nombre_hijo"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // user is not found with the credentials
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Los datos estan mal. Por favor intenta nuevamente!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required post params is missing
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Se requiere el dato (id de grupo). Intentalo nuevamente!";
echo json_encode($response);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en el modo en el que accedes a los resultados, al utilizar una sentencia preparada tenes dos alternativas, bindear los campos u obtener el resultado y pedir loas arrays para las rows:

La correccion estaria en que debes pedir el resultado una unica vez, asi

```
public function searchMiembrosGrupo($id_grupo){

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `email_padre`,`nombre_hijo` FROM `hijos` INNER JOIN `user` WHERE `hijos`.`email_padre` = `user`.`email` AND `user`.`grupo` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $miembros_grupo = array();

        while ($row = result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($miembros_grupo,$row);
        }
        return $miembros_grupo;
    }
```

O sino podes bindear los resultados, de esta manera:

```
public function searchMiembrosGrupo($id_grupo){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `email_padre`,`nombre_hijo` FROM `hijos` INNER JOIN `user` WHERE `hijos`.`email_padre` = `user`.`email` AND `user`.`grupo` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email_padre,$nombre_hijo);

    $miembros_grupo = array();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $row = arraw("email_padre" => $email_padre, "nombre_hijo" => $nombre_hijo);
        array_push($miembros_grupo,$row);
    }
    return $miembros_grupo;
}
```

Ambas son igual de validas, en lo personal prefiero la segunda si es que no necesito el objeto del resultado para nada particular y solo pretendo usar los datos de los campos. Espero haya solucionado tu problema

Comment: Ps probe el primer metodo pero no logro acceder a los registros desde el archivo en donde se retornan los valores del array.

Comment: Perdon, se me dío por copiar el código tuyo y no me fije que habias cambiado el `id_grupo` por `email` y por eso no funcionaba la consulta. Muchisimas Gracias @Sacha

Comment: Cuidado, en tu pregunta esta usando esa variable, yo copie tu codigo, jajaj me agrada haberte podido ayudar